# How to correctly mount volume in docker compose azure webapp

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose, azure-web-app-service, devops

I have an azure webapp using their docker compose option. I have read a few posts on it, and have my compose file set up as so:

```
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ifttstorage:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: elovation
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pw

 web:
    image: acriftt.azurecr.io/attempt2:latest
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    volumes:
      - .:/elovation
    ports:
      - "4321:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      RAILS_ENV: production

volumes:
  ifttstorage:
    driver: azure_file
    driver_opts:
      share_name: ifttfileshare
      storage_account_name: ifttsa
      storage_account_key: key
```

I then have a storage mount on my webapp, named ifttstorage, pointing to the storage account ifttsa, the storage container ifttfileshare, and the mount path /var/lib/postgresql/data.

No matter what small changes I make, the webapp does not launch properly, and i get the following error message:

```
2024-03-12T00:11:38.012Z INFO  - Starting multi-container app..
2024-03-12T00:11:38.012Z ERROR - Exception in multi-container config parsing: YamlException: (Line: 5, Col: 9, Idx: 57) - (Line: 5, Col: 40, Idx: 88): Bind mount must start with ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}.
```

I may be missing something obvious, I am fairly new to this kind of deployment. Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: The "bind mount" text refers to the `web` container.  The syntax you have there tries to use a local directory, which won't work in a cloud context.  What user-managed persistent data is being stored in the `/elovation` directory; can you also move it to a named volume?  It sort of looks like this might be trying to inject source code from the host replacing all of the content in the container, which isn't usually a best practice; can you delete the `volumes:` and the `command:` override from the `web` container?

Comment: @DavidMaze I tried removing it and I still get the same error, whether i have the named volume or not.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you’re encountering indicates that the bind mount path in your Docker Compose configuration must start with the ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME} environment variable. This is a requirement for Azure Web Apps when using persistent storage. Here’s how you can adjust your Docker Compose file to comply with this requirement:

```
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/ifttstorage:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: elovation
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pw

  web:
    image: acriftt.azurecr.io/attempt2:latest
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    volumes:
      - ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/elovation:/elovation
    ports:
      - "4321:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      RAILS_ENV: production

volumes:
  ifttstorage:
    driver: azure_file
    driver_opts:
      share_name: ifttfileshare
      storage_account_name: ifttsa
      storage_account_key: key
```

Make sure to replace the volume paths with ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME} followed by your desired path within the storage mount. Additionally, ensure that the WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE setting is set to true in your application settings to enable persistent storage. This should resolve the error and allow your web app to launch properly. Remember to test your configuration after making these changes.